# How to determines the average length of a string within a text file

Tags: python, string

I am trying to determine the average length of a set of strings I have pulled out from a text file, I am supposed to find the average length of strings that have exclamation marks

I used this to pull out all the words followed by an exclamation mark:

```
Exclaim = re.findall(r’\w+[!]’, pride)
```

But now I have to find the average length of these strings, I have tried using the `split()` function but it gives me this error:

> ‘list’ object has no attribute ‘split’ using python

Comment: Do you need the length of the words or the lines?  It's an important distinction.

Comment: There's no need to put `!` inside `[]`. Just use `\w+!`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`split()` function doesn't work because the output of `re.findall()` is a list. `split()` function takes a string, and converts it to list. If you wish to calculate the average string length of your list of strings, it's as simple as this:

```
avglen = sum(map(len, Exclaim)) / len(Exclaim)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, can you explain what map is? Sorry I’m still so new

Comment: `map` returns an iterator that you can use to apply a function on each item of the iterable object. In this case it takes the `Exclaim` list and apply `len` function on each item of Exclaim.

Comment: So basically it's like `sum(string_characters_length) / total_number_of_strings`